# Output does not match with the choices given in the MCQ

Tags: c

Its a simple C program I found in a book.

```
static char wer[3][4] = {"bag", "let", "bud"};
char(*ptr) [4] = wer;
```

The possible output of `printf("%d %d", ptr, ptr+1);` is

```
(a) 262 262
(b) 262 266
(c) 262 263
(d) 262 265
```

When I executed the same program, it gave me 170 174 output
Can anyone please explain me the initialization of *ptr and why the answer is not one of the answers given in MCQ.

Attached is the pic of [Questions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xctNS.jpg) and an [Explanation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NxZGf.jpg)

Comment: printing pointers using `%d` format is undefined behaviour. Printing pointers will give you the value where the machine stored the address, very unlikely the same as in your book...

Comment: Which book is this from? You should probably recycle it and get a good one.

Comment: To me "The possible output" suggests that the book might be trying to ask what the **difference** between the two pointers would be and giving values just as examples; that is, the only thing that would matter would be the distance between them, not their own values. Still, it apparently didn't make that clear and is using an ill-formed `printf()` statement to do it, so it doesn't seem to be a very well written exercise.

Comment: `printf("%d %d", ptr, ptr+1);` -> `printf("%p %p", (void*)ptr, (void*)(ptr+1));`.

Comment: "I found in a book." Name it.People should come to know which book they should not read/refer.

Comment: @underscore_d well, if it describes using "%d" for printing pointers, perhaps a museum of antiquities would be interested in it :)

Comment: Seems like making a wiki of bad books

Comment: Its a local author book named MCQs Computer Science by Bhatti brothers

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should use `%p` to print an address. Read Michael Walz's comment. Else, you are invoking [UB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Next, `char(*ptr) [4] = wer;` this defines `ptr` to be a pointer to an array of four `char`s. As you must be aware, adding `1` to a pointer makes the pointer jump the number of bytes that the pointer is a type of. For example, in `int *p`, when you do `p++` you will jump `sizeof int` number of bytes.

Similarly, in your case you will jump 4 bytes because the type of `ptr` is a pointer to an-array-of-4-chars (read that under one breath ;)). The answer should be b.

> why the answer is not one of the answers given in MCQ

That's because, you are printing (or trying to) the address of an object. Everytime a program runs, there is no guarantee that the objects will be placed in the same location.

BTW, I would suggest you to get another book. Quick.